# How to create a div which contains two elements in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to javaScript and I need help.
I am trying to create a div which consists of two elements and after that I want to append it on a specific class. Here is what I have come up so far:

`<body>
 <div class="myClass"></div>
 </body>`

For simplicity, I have only included codes which I believe are significant.

```
  <script>
  var div1 = document.createElement("div");
  div1.className = "note";
  var btn1= document.createElement("button");
  btn1.className = "btn";
  var impt1= document.createElement("input");
  impt1.className = "impt";
  div1.append(impt1);
  $("#myClass").append(div1);
  </script>
```

The problem with the above code is that instead of giving me just a single apended div which contains button and input, it gives me a button and some undesired box and no input field. Can anyone help me how to get the right output. The desired solution is to create a div which contains button and input field that is appended to myClass using javaScript. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in right path, You have note referencing to jQuery  hence `$(".myClass").append(div1);` is not working. This can be achieved using.

```
document.querySelector('.myClass').append(div1);
```

```js
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
div1.className = "note";

var btn1 = document.createElement("button");
btn1.className = "btn";
btn1.textContent = "btn";

var impt1 = document.createElement("input");
impt1.className = "impt";

div1.append(btn1);
div1.append(impt1);

document.querySelector('.myClass').append(div1);
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

---

If you are using jQuery.

```js
var div1 = $("<div>", {
  "class": "note"
});
var btn1 = $("<button>", {
  "class": "btn",
  "text": "btn"
});

var impt1 = $("<input>", {
  "class": "impt"
});

div1.append(btn1);
div1.append(impt1);

$('.myClass').append(div1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
  div1.className = "note";
  var btn1= document.createElement("button");
  btn1.className = "btn";
  btn1.innerHTML = "btn";
  var impt1= document.createElement("input");
  impt1.className = "impt";
  div1.append(btn1);
  div1.append(impt1);
  $(".myClass").append(div1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class="myClass"></div>
 </body>
```